# magento 2.1 is not installing in ubuntu machine

Tags: php, mysql, magento, ubuntu

I am installing Magento Community Edition 2.1.0 . I have followed all these steps: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-configure-magento-on-ubuntu-14-04

My PHP version is `PHP 7.0.9-1+deb.sury.org~trusty+1 (cli) ( NTS )` and MySQL version : `mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.6.3, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper`

Still it showing same message when I typed localhost/Magento:

> Magento supports PHP 5.6, 7.0.2, and 7.0.6 or later. Please read Magento System Requirements.